# XULRunner 30.0 Upgrade

Tags: macos, firefox, xulrunner

I have an Mac OS X app working fine on XULRunner ver 18.0.

Now I am upgrading the XULRunner version from 18.0 to 30.0. Have followed the steps below:

1. Downloaded the XULRunner 30.0 Runtime
2. Remove the content from XULRunner.Framework directory
3. Copied the latest files downloaded in XULRunner 30.0 Runtime
4. Now while launching the application, I am getting this error:

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: @executable_path/libmozglue.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/USER/Desktop/*/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/xulrunner
  Reason: image not found

Comment: So, where is `libmozglue.dylib`? The error message clearly says that it should be there but isn't.

Comment: It's there only in "Contents/Frameworks/XUL.framework/Versions/Current". Working fine for 18.0 but showing error in 30.0.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately XULRunner is not well supported, but I was able to get around most of the errors and get it working, except for one issue which I will get to later.

Basically, all the instructions I can find for how to structure the bundle are outdated. [Mozilla had to restructure the binaries due to changes in the Mac code signing layout requirements](http://hearsum.ca/blog/upcoming-changes-to-mac-package-layout-signing.html). From [this bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1105044) and some trial and error I was able to determine the layout requirements.

The first error we can see when running the `Contents/MacOS/xulrunner` binary from the command line.

#### Error 1:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/libmozglue.dylib

The entirety of the `XUL.framework` contents must be placed into the App's `Contents/MacOS/` directory. So to fix this error, copy everything from `XUL.framework/Versions/Current` into your app's `MacOS` directory.

Ok, now the binary will run. However, that brings us to the next error which can also be seen from the command line.

#### Error 2:

> Couldn't load XPCOM.

This error is anything but descriptive, but to solve it you simple need to copy the `dependentlibs.list` file (now in your `MacOS` directory) to your `Contents/Resources/` directory.

#### Error 3:

Now when you run by the command line, you will get something like the following.

```
Mozilla XULRunner 36.0.4

Usage: xulrunner [OPTIONS]
       xulrunner APP-FILE [APP-OPTIONS...]

OPTIONS
      --app                  specify APP-FILE (optional)
  -h, --help                 show this message
  -v, --version              show version
  --gre-version              print the GRE version string on stdout

APP-FILE
  Application initialization file.

APP-OPTIONS
  Application specific options.
```

Unfortunately, `xulrunner` is not automatically finding the `application.ini` file in `Contents/Resources`. For testing, we can force it through the command line. Something like the following will do the trick:

```
./MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/xulrunner MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/application.ini
```

At the moment, the only possible solution to this last issue I can offer at the moment is to make a stud loaded, either a shell script or compiled binary that executes the necessary command to run `application.ini` in `xulrunner`.

Comment: Superb timing! I was just about to start the same battle. Thanks.